# Wakanda callMethod synchronous mode

Tags: wakanda

I'm trying to use callMethod() from a method executed on the server.

In this case, I should be able to call it in synchronous mode. However, through trial and error I have found that in this context (i.e. on the server), the method requires three parameters rather than the two mentioned in the docs.

It requires

- the first parameter to be a string
- the second parameter to be an array
- the third parameter to be an object

I've tried quite a few combinations with these parameters but nothing seems to work. At the same time, Wakanda doesn't throw an error as long as the parameters are in the correct form.

Any ideas would be more than welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose we have two variable, one containing the name of the dataClass and the second the name of the dataClass's method :

```
var myDataClass = "User";
var myMethod = "addUser";
```

To use the dataClass 'User' and call the method  'addUser' you can do it this way :

```
var currentClass = ds.dataClasses[myDataClass];
currentClass[myMethod]()
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply – I had to move onto another project for a few weeks and I've only just now been able to get back to this.

Comment: YES!! That's exactly what I needed and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The method callMethod() is a clientSide method, it should be used on prototyper Js files.
try to use it on a button.click event :

```
    button1.click = function button1_click (event)
{
    ds.User.callMethod({method:"method1", onSuccess:myFunction, onError:failure});

        function myFunction(){
            return true;
        }
        function failure(){
            return false;
        }
};
```

To call method in a serverSide js File in a synchronous mode, you can just make the call in this manner :

```
var test = ds.User.method1();
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to call a method on the server.   What I want to do is call a method by name rather than by reference. That is I want to set up the name of a method like the following  `methodName = "ds."+className+".doSomething"`  Then run  `callMethod(methodName);`